# Validation and throwing an exception inside a Flux is not working

Tags: java, java-8, try-catch, flux

I am trying to validate the values of a `list` using a `reactor.core.publisher.Flux` inside a `try catch`, but when `map` throws the exception the `catch` doesn't catch it at all. I don't really understand what's happening here. Some help would be appreciate.

This is exactly what I am trying to do:

```
 public Flux<Something> execute(final List<Line> lines) {
        try {
          return this.getFlux(lines)
              .map(line -> this.validateLine(line))//this throws my custom exception if the condition applies
              .map(line -> this.doSomething(line))
              .map(line -> this.doSomethingElse(line));

        } catch (myCustomException e) {
            return something;
        }
  }
```

I can see the `validate` method works well and throws the exception by debugging but the `catch` doesn't seem to be working and I can't see what is wrong.

Comment: Is this really related to java streams and not reactive pipeline with `Flux`?

Comment: Actually yes, this is related with `Flux`, I have never seen them before, i am trying to understand how they work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a terminal operation applied onto the end of the stream. Streams are evaluated lazily.